# What are the advantages of faster server side scripting languages?

Tags: php, python, performance, scripting, webserver

Typical performance of Python scripts are about [5 times faster](http://blog.dhananjaynene.com/2008/07/performance-comparison-c-java-python-ruby-jython-jruby-groovy/) than PHP. What are the advantages of using faster server side scripting languages? Will the speed ever be felt by website visitors? Can PHP's performance be compensated by faster server processors?

Comment: I happen to think he didn't code inside PHP's paradigm, which would have been faster.

Comment: He can't be using a PHP bytecode cache (e.g. APC), because he's running the tests in CLI mode.  So the testing environment hamstrings PHP performance in a crucial way.

Comment: "Typical performance" ??? You refer to one tiny program which quite obviously isn't typical of PHP scripts :-) These aren't typical PHP scripts either but at least there's more than one - http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python&lang2=php&box=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Andy B. King, in *Website Optimization*:

> For Google an increase in page load time from 0.4 second to 0.9 seconds decreased traffic and ad revenues by 20%. For Amazon every 100 ms increase in load times decreased sales with 1%.

http://www.svennerberg.com/2008/12/page-load-times-vs-conversion-rates/

But even though Python is ~4 times faster, by and large it's the architecture of the software that makes the biggest difference. If your queries and disk access are unoptimized, then you have a massive bottleneck—even when you're just including some 20 different files (5ms seek time equals 100ms). I'm certain that even Python can be slowed by inefficiencies and database queries, just as badly as PHP can.

That said, unfriendly interfaces will cost you more, in the long run, than the decrease in speed will. Just make a registration form with no explanation and fifteen required fields, with strict validation, and you'll scare tons of people away. (In my own opinion.)

Answer (score 10):

How about [when you get charged for CPU time](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Resources)?

> I just saved a ton of money by switching to Python!

Answer (score 4):

For typical web apps, the difference in speed won't usually be felt within the request itself (the network latency dwarfs your compute time for a typical script that runs inside an HTTP request).

There are plenty of *other* things that affect scalability, but the processing needs to handle an average request does factor in.  So, a lonely user will not feel the difference.  A user who is one of many might feel the difference, as the server infrastructure struggles with load.

Of course, throwing more processor will mitigate the issue, but as jrockway says, maintaining two servers is significantly more than twice as hard as maintaining one.

All of that said, in the vast majority of cases, your bottlenecks will not be processor.  You'll be running out of memory, or you'll find that your database interaction is the real bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the execution speed of web request handlers usually translates to handling more requests/second with the same hardware.  This is valuable in a number of cases; maintaining one server is much easier than maintaining two.

BTW, why Python and not Haskell?  Haskell is 100x faster than PHP in some benchmarks.

Comment: Benchmarks are ambiguous; assemble a full web application with database queries, etc, and then benchmark the whole application and average its requests-per-second and *then* compare against PHP and *maybe* it'll be more accurate.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Haskell!  I love Python, and it's certainly a better choice than PHP if performance is important, but if you really care about performance, you need one of C++ (OK), Haskell (better), or C (best).  If you want performance and a highly powerful language with an excellent interactive environment, then Haskell is your best choice.

Comment: Which benchmarks? (and along those lines, why not just write everything in C? ;-)

Comment: David, I thought we programmers were supposed to avoid giving ourselves eyebleeds?  :-D

Comment: C++ performance is not as good as straight C? Um, no, not unless you're using bloatware libraries.

Comment: I have measured this stuff.  The database is not as slow as you think it is.

Comment: Honest benchmarking is hard to do. I have been looking for a nice benchmark of available JVM implementations, can't find anything that's decent and recent.